# Meteor accounts suite: Merge accounts based on email address

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Note**: this has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485764/5223245) but that's from 2013 and things might have changed. I don't have the rep to add a comment.

I'm building out a prototype with Meteor and noticed when I log in with Twitter and then Facebook (and then Google), three separate user accounts are created. Is there any built in way to make sure these are merged? I'm not seeing any email address in the twitter based user account, so I can see it might be difficult to figure out which accounts to link.

I have looked in the [**Meteor issue queue**](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues?page=1&q=merge+accounts&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and found [**PR#270**](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/270) but that's the same solution as proposed in the old answer above.

I just want to make sure I haven't missed an option in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution from: [Practical ways of dealing with duplicate accounts using OAUTH in Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237154/practical-ways-of-dealing-with-duplicate-accounts-using-oauth-in-meteor)

It is to use the [accounts-meld](https://atmospherejs.com/splendido/accounts-meld) package. I'm yet to use or test it. This is not ideal however, I'd like to see a core config kind of a solution if one exists.